# button is not responding click once class is changed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4-5 div and need to hide and show them on the click of next button. so, I am changing the class of the button on every click. But my button is responding click for the first time and later class is changing but not responding click to the current class.

Here is My code Sample:

```
$(".next_btn.second").on("click",function(){ alert("second");
        $(".ugc_page.second").addClass("hide");
        $(".ugc_event3.second").addClass("hide");
        $(".ugc_page.third").removeClass("hide");
        $(".next_btn").removeClass("second").addClass("third");
        $(".previous_btn").removeClass("second").addClass("active third");

    });

    $(".next_btn.third").on('click',function() {alert('third');
        $(".ugc_page.third").addClass("hide");
        $(".ugc_page.fourth").removeClass("hide");
        $(".next_btn").removeClass("third").addClass("fourth");
        $(".previous_btn").removeClass("third").addClass("active fourth");
    });
```

On first click, it is changing the class to third but when click alert is second only.

Comment: You need to rebind the elements if u replace the class. So after you add new class and remove previous one, you need to rebind the click event. Plus I would suggest, this is not a good way to do this. There is better way to accomplish this without rebinding again and again.

Comment: please elaborate..

Comment: can you provide html?

Comment: `$(".next_btn").removeClass("second").addClass("third");` after this you should execute `$(".next_btn.third").on('click',function() ...`

Comment: <div class="next_btn active second">NEXT</div>

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use `Index` of the element `div` as the trigger for hiding.

Then on your javascript declare a `var count = 0`

Each Click of next increment the `count`.

```html
$('#next-button').on("click" function(){
  count++; // increment (decrement if its prev-button)
  $('.DIV_class').fadeOut(0); // hide all class
  $('.DIV_class').eq(count).fadeIn(0); // will show only the index of that class.
});
```

Its more easy to maintain and readable.

I haven't tested this code but hope it give you idea.